# Django Template Wont Display Complex String

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I've got a list in my view, and I am trying to output it to a template. The code for this is:

```
 {% for user in list %}
        <tr class="{{ user.1 }}">
            {% for item in user %}
                <td class="{% autoescape off %}{{item}}{% endautoescape %}">{% autoescape off %}{{item}}{% endautoescape %}</td>
            {%endfor%}
        </tr>
    {%endfor%}
```

The code itself works fine, however it will not print an element in the list if it is overly complex. It has no issue printing the same element if it is "test", however when it is populated with actual data, it displays a blank field, an moves onto the next element.
I cannot show you the exact data, but it contains speech marks, slashes, various letters and sometimes a percent. the string is usually around 25 chars long,
Thank you!

 **EDIT**: Thought I'd add that playing with autoescape doesn't help
The data that i'm trying to output is: 
`b"\x11\xb4\xc7\xabhM@\x04\x87\x00\xb9kV\xeet\x9d'[\xfb\x7f\x9bE\xd1P"`
The entire list is:

```
[2, '<client>', '<acc_no>', '<username>', False, b"\x11\xb4\xc7\xabhM@\x04\x87\x00\xb9kV\xeet\x9d'[\xfb\x7f\x9bE\xd1P", 0]]
```

Comment: Have you checked the source of the HTML that is generated by the template? Maybe the browser is just hiding the text for some reason. Did you try the "|safe" filter?

Comment: You are already passing list of list. can you explain overly complex items. if item is empty it would display nothing, try printing the list in the views and see the structure. then construct template according to that.

Comment: @data is right. Almost certainly you are generating a malformed HTML code. Check the actual source code.

Comment: I have printed the list in the views, and it comes out as it should. It is printing out the rest of the list fine, it's just that one section which it is ignoring..
In the HTML I'm getting <td class=""></td> for that field